# Dividing a bag of mixed candy

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics

Assuming I have a bag of candy **C**i with **N** pieces of candy. It's a mix of **t** different types of candy, **T**i. I want to share it between my **M** friends.

Each of them has a preference for each type of candy, **P**(m,**T**i) where **m** is one of the **M** friends. **P**(m,**T**i) is an integer and distinct, and the sum of **P**(m,**T**) for each friend is 50 (each friend distributes 50 points as he wishes between the candy types, with no types getting the same amount of points).

We want to divide the **N** pieces of candy between all the **m** friends in such a way that everybody is pleased. All the candy needs to be divided. Each person does not need to be given the same amount of candy.

1) Is there any way to objectively reach a solution for the "perfect" way to divide the candy?

Assuming the answer to (1) is "no", we will define it as follows. **S**m is sum[**P**(m,**T**j)], where **j** is subset of **i** that **m** is given. The definition of the optimal solution is the distribution with the lowest possible standard deviation of **S**m with highest possible average **S**m as tie breaker.

2) What is the best way to approach this problem? Is there any known algorithms?

Comment: You haven't said what your metric for best (or perfect) is. The approach where each takes one in turn favours the first picker. If their preferences are nearly even (each type given a similar score) they may pick a slight favourite that deprives a later picker of the chance to take their strong favourite. e.g. 2 friends, 2 types of sweets, one of each, P(1,1) = 26, P(1,2) = 24, P(2,1) = 49 P(2,2) = 1. Letting friend 2 have type 1 seems a better solution, but that wont happen if friend 1 picks first.

Comment: Exactly, so the question is, how do you find the optimal approach/algorithm to divide the candy by.

I haven't said what the metric is, because there seems like there should be a way to phrase an optimal solution where everybody is as happy as can be expected that I am not aware of.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because is not related to software programming.

Comment: How can one say what an optimal solution is without a metric to compare whether one solution is better than another? If one creates a measure for the happiness of one person as a function of their sweets and the preference values they've assigned, there's still the question of whether (for example) you are trying to maximise total happiness scores or maximise the happiness of the least happy person, it seems you're not aiming to maximise the maximum individual happiness (the algorithm for that is just give one person all the sweets).

Comment: @BrentWorden If this question is not related to software programming, how would you solve this problem without programming a software ?

Answer (score 0):

For (2), we can find a starting point by letting each friend in turn pick a piece of candy until the bag is empty. Each friend will always pick the candy with the highest preference. We have to calculate **S**m for multiple solutions where we alternate the pick order. This should yields us the best starting point.

A Genetic algorithm can the be used to further find better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

(1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency. A Pareto improvement is a change to a different allocation that makes at least one individual or preference criterion better off without making any other individual or preference criterion worse off, given a certain initial allocation of goods among a set of individuals. An allocation is defined as "Pareto efficient" or "Pareto optimal" when no further Pareto improvements can be made, in which case we are assumed to have reached Pareto optimality.

Comment: that approach is not guaranteed to give an optimal solution, since it is restricted by the score of the initial allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd consider whether you model the problem such that you can apply a version of "the Hungarian Algorithm" to it. Even if not, that could be a useful start point to search for similar approaches.

As a heuristic approach I'd suggest you be better allocating not in a fixed order but in terms of who is least happy with the sweets they have so far and by
trying to order the people in terms of how hard they are to please (for example someone who allocates most of their 50 points to one type is going to be hard to please, especially if there aren't many of that type of sweets).